# Unable to build android app because ofKeystore file '/Users/name/Desktop/KEYSTORE/release.keystore' not found for signing config 'release'

Tags: android, android-studio

I have cloned a project already created and failed to build the app in release.keystore. So I again generated the keystore still getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

in app level `build.gradle` find these two parts and comment them:

```
//part one
signingConfigs {
    my_app_sign_config {
        
    }
}

//part two
signingConfig signingConfigs.my_app_sign_config
```